# Locking windows on desktop in Openbox

Tags: desktop, openbox

How can I protect a window from being hidden by the `ToggleShowDesktop` global action?

I've found that Openbox 3.5 can do that trick only for windows with the desktop or dock type. For example, windows created by `trayer`, `conky` or IDesktop will not be hiden by the `ToggleShowDesktop` global action. But these programs create windows of desired type on startup. While I want to make this trick possible for any already created window. For example Chromium browser.

Possible workarounds:

1. Protect desired window from hiding (Iconify/minimize).
2. Change type of desired window to `desktop` or `dock` by some script binded to hotkey.

But the [Openbox actions reference](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aActions) doesn't have such a command. And secondly, I'm not familiar with the Linux window system to write a script that will change the type of a window on the fly.